How can I modify all elements within a kdb list stored as a binary file
I have a kdb binary file being stored that I'm getting using
c:get `:/opt/test/groups;

This is a symbol list containing a list of groups, if I want to update all the elements in this list to be 'test' for example and store it again in another variable c1, how can I do this.


You could replace elements using amend after the get
/replace all
q)@[get`:mylist;::;:;`test]
`test`test`test`test

/replace first 2
q)@[get`:mylist;0 1;:;`test]
`test`test`CCC`DDD

though if you're replacing all then you really just need count+take
q)count[get`:mylist]#`test
`test`test`test`test

